# How centering polish numbers in tabular

Tags: latex, pdflatex

```
 \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
  \hline numer & błąd \\
  \hline 11,1 &  11\\
  \hline 299,05  &  10,1\\
  \hline 3000,5 &  9,3\\ 
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

In my country using , not . as separator. I cant use 'S' in tabular header. How centering to comma in tabular enviroments?

I need table with centering by the comma in numbers. I can use `r@{\,}` but header is not centered.

Comment: Can you clarify if there are other reasons to not use siunitx or just the decimal marker? Because you could change it to a comma with `\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input 'e'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `siunitx` has an option to use `,` as decimal marker (if you compile with lualatex or xelatex, you don't need this `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont` hack...):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}


 \begin{tabular}{ | S[table-format=4.2] | S[table-format=2.1] | }
  \hline {numer} & {\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont błąd}\\
  \hline 11,1 &  11\\
  \hline 299,05  &  10,1\\
  \hline 3000,5 &  9,3\\ 
  \hline
 \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: must be \makecell and [table-format=4.2] in S options